# Hive exception with custom SerDe

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hql

I'm trying to use hive with a custom SerDe and StorageHandler classes.
When I try to run a hive query using the new SerDe, I get the following exception with no other details.

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I tried logging information inside the StorageHandler and it seems it was created successfully but the SerDe initialize function wasn't called.

Is there an obvious reason for this exception or an easy way to debug it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I only looked at the logs produced in hive CLI and didn't check `/tmp/$user/hive.log` and the problem was a missing class in the built jar.